# Query to join fact table to bridge table and show bridge group rows in one row

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, oracle-sql-developer

I have a data warehouse with a One-To-Many relationship:

```
"Fact" table contains: Product_Group_ID
"Product_Bridge" table contains: Product_Group_ID, Product_ID
"Product" table contains: Product_ID, Product_Name, other product attributes..
```

I've inserted the data into the relevant tables, but how can I query the database and retrieve all products from a product group in the one row result? I've never used a bridge table before and could not find any decent/helpful examples online for how to actually query between the bridge/fact/dimensions.

i.e. the desired result would look like:

```
product_group_ID product_ID product_name product_ID_1 product_name1 product_ID_n product_name_n
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to retrieve one row for a each product_group_ID, and a column of this row contains a string that is the concatenation of the values product_group_ID, product_ID, product_name, product_ID_1, product_name1, ...,  product_ID_ and  product_name_n, Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example output you can use LISTAGG. The basic query that you can add whatever other criteria to is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.product_group_id ||' '|| LISTAGG(c.product_id||'  '||c.product_name, ' ')
                                   WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY p.product_group_id, c.product_id)
                                   OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_group_id))
  FROM product c
       INNER JOIN
       product_bride p ON c.product_id = p.product_id
```

If you need more attributes from the product then you will need to concatenate them in the LISTAGG. I haven't included a join to the Fact table but that can easily be included if you need something from it.